# How to execute Angular ng-click directive inside custom component on enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom icon component using isolate scope where a user can define what he or she wants to happen on ng-click:

```
<ers-icon name="history" ng-click="ctrl.clickAlert('history')"></ers-icon>
```

This calls a method from within the user's controller as follows:

```
this.clickAlert = function (icon) {
     alert("You selected the " + icon + " icon.");
}
```

I need to add enter key functionality to the icon component without adding any other code, from I have above, to my html element. So essentially listen for the enter key press from within the directive and evaluate the ng-click directive on ers-icon. Here is what I have as the icon directive:

```
// on click works fine
.on("click", (event:JQueryEventObject):void => {
            if (this.ngDisabled) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    }


//execute whatever function is specified inside ng-click on enter key press
.on("keydown", (event:JQueryEventObject):void => {
       if (event.keyCode === 13) {
               if (this.ngDisabled) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   event.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                   // need to execute ng-click here

                   // this try doesn't work, gives me undefined
                   $scope.$apply(() => {
                       $scope.$eval($attr.ngClick);
                   }
                }
             }
        });
```

This runs fine on enter key press but I can't get the controller function defined on ng-click to run.

I thought maybe $eval or $parse would work but it looks like those will only evaluate expressions within {{}}. What is the best way to execute that ng-click attribute so that when a user hits the enter key, the "this.clickAlert" function is ran and an alert is shown on the screen?

I can't really change any of the code as is above, just looking for the solution within the else statement of the on keydown listener.

Comment: dont recommend using $eval

Comment: you can try to  also pass the ngClick as a function in the directive scope and call it.  

scope:{
    ngClick:'&'
}

in your directive's link function you can then call it like this $scope.ngClick;  See this example..http://codepen.io/btinoco96/pen/qqYPPp?editors=1011

Comment: I seem to be getting a syntax error here "$scope.ngClick" that says its "expecting an assignment or function call"

Comment: It works fine for me (just tried it), I click on the "my directive"  and it shows me an alert.  The alert is triggered by a function in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
.on("keydown", (event:JQueryEventObject):void => {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           if (this.ngDisabled) {
               event.preventDefault();
               event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
               // need to execute ng-click here
               this.element.trigger("click");
            }
         }
    });
```